# Why does Speech to text websites are not working in my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop?

Tags: sound, 18.04, microphone

When I select to search by voice of [Google search](https://www.google.com/), it is saying **No Internet Connection** as shown below.

[image]

Along with Google voice search, [dictation](https://dictation.io/), [voice notebook](https://voicenotebook.com/), [Speech notes](https://speechnotes.co/), [Google voice to text](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/4492226?hl=en), all websites I tried so far for the purpose of speech to text conversion are not working. Since a week I found no website that can convert my speech to text.

I installed [SpeechNotes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.speechnotes.speechnotes) and several other apps on my Android mobile phone for speech to text conversion, all are working properly either with or without proxy.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. It is mandatory to use a proxy in my laptop. But I did check with both proxy and without a proxy, not working in both cases. My mic is working properly. I checked through [this](https://www.onlinemictest.com) site, both with and without a proxy.

By mic test (with and without proxy), we can say that there is no issue with mic and browser, (as well as proxy). Since I can use speech to text in my Android mobile either with or without proxy, we can say that there is no issue with proxy. So, there can be only issue with using speech to text websites in Ubuntu.

What have do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Does anyone using Ubuntu 18.04 readily have any website that can do speech to text conversion? Please comment if any website does that.

Comment: I'm using on google chrome... I checked on both browsers, wherever compatible.

Comment: @user68186 With microphone?

Comment: @user68186 for 2nd site, it is showing  
**Confidence level  : error network**

Comment: Yeah, I am using proxy, but checked without proxy too.... not working under any situation....

Comment: I did not try with windows, but laptop is mine, i have to use it via proxy only, I connected to mobile internet (without proxy) and checked. I tried with my lab systems with Ubuntu, there also not working. Feeling that you are lucky....

Comment: One more thing to try: Boot Ubuntu with Live USB and connect to the Internet and try again. You will have to download and install Chrome which will temporary for that session only.

Comment: Same problem `$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
$ uname -a
Linux lrkwz-Precision-M4500 4.15.0-38-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:59:38 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ chromium-browser --version
Chromium 70.0.3538.67 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04
`

Answer (score 0):

a) Make sure you are using Google Chrome

b) Speaking near the mic and loud enough

c) Turned on the mic in settings.

Juste tested in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with Google Chrome, and it works.
The following article is updated with troubleshooting.

https://www.debugpoint.com/2018/07/speech-recognition-to-text-in-linux-ubuntu-using-google-docs/